# Could Senzu Beans cure diseases as well?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-z

Senzu bean is known as "magical healing bean", it can heal and restore consumer's health instantly when eaten. Does it cures diseases as well? Such as Goku's heart disease.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If Senzu bean could cure diseases, Goku wouldn't have died in the future and Trunks wouldn't have needed to go back from the future to give him the antidote.

From [Dragon ball wikia](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Senzu_Bean)

> However, it appears that the beans can not heal injuries that have
>   already healed over (like Tien's and Yamcha's respective scars or
>   Saiyan tails) or cure ailments (like Goku's heart virus contracted
>   during the Androids Saga)

Comment: to add on further proof to this, Goku ate a Senzu in his fight against 19 as i recall (Though I remember this from TFS's abridged, but I doubt they animated/stitched that scene themselves) It did nothing for that Heart Virus.

Answer (score 0):

NO.

Senzu bean only help to recover from injury, heal the wounds and regain power.
It could not be used as a medicine to cure disease, and the evidence can be found during the Android Saga, where Future Trunks bought the antidote from the future to help Goku survive the heart attack.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because it was  EXPLAINED by Future Trunks in the  Android Arc that Senzu Beans, in his timeline, were stopped being manufactured because of the decrease in need of it and the time to make a senzu bean would take long, thus the heart disease that Goku contracted were not cured.

Answer (score -1):

While there's little concrete evidence, it's likely that Senzu Bean's only heal the type of wounds your body could heal on its own, in Dragonball it was noted that Senzu bean's were very filling, not quite like medicine. So it could be more like they're a "super food" that accelerates the body's natural processes rather than something like conventional medicine.